# How can I make locate able the hibernate cfgxml file?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

[its my simple index.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xa47.png)

[My cgf.xml file which I created through the hibernate module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXV20.png)

[Controller File Where the request is landning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBTaR.png)

[I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoHUD.png)
Everything is in the right place but still, I am getting the same error every time, Which is cfg.xml is not found, I also changed the directory but not worked at all for me.

I have the xml base configuration.Here is my web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">


    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.inov8"></ctx:component-scan>

</beans>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask nand improve your question. Hint, don't let people click links to get an overview, and include actual code instead of screenshots (the latter become unreadable). And please include your spirng config, which is what contains the error.

Comment: thanks for guiding me,In future ill apply these things.

Comment: Again please add the code not links. Your controller is flawed remove the `src/main/resources` part in your loading (it will load from the root of the classpath). Also you shouldn't be doing it like this instead use the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` from Spring to configure the sessionfactory in xml and then just inject it.

Answer (score -1):

by default Hibernate configuration file must be located in root folder (src) under name

```
hibernate.cfg.xml
```

if you want to rename it or change the location, you must give it's path in Configure() method.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("your hibernate.cfg.xml path");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I also tried this.sadly it's not working.

Comment: `src/main/resources` is the root of the classpath. Placing it in `src` will make it undetectable.